# Run dtsx package from bat file on remote computer

Tags: ssis

I have created a `dtsx` package that performs data updates on an SQL table.
If I run the package from the server where SSIS is installed it runs correctly.
Then I generated a .bat file to be able to run that package from a remote pc.
If I run the bat file with the same user with whom I generated the package it gives me the following error (the server has Standard Edition installed):

> **Error: 2020-04-30 12: 24: 15.24    Code: 0xC000F427    Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline    Description: To run a SSIS package outside
>   of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of
>   Integration Services or higher. End Error**

If I run it with another
 user (other than the one who created the package) it throws the
 following error:

> **Started: 12:28:26 Error: 2020-04-30 12: 28: 26.49    Code: 0xC0011007    Source: {9A5E45AB-9790-4942-8639-F8C38A51D202}
>      Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package
>   does not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be
>   posted. End Error Error: 2020-04-30 12: 28: 26.49    Code: 0xC0011002
>      Source: {9A5E45AB-9790-4942-8639-F8C38A51D202}    Description:
>   Failed to open package file "\ areskerjcmdz01 \ c $ \ Users \
>   pamartinez_admin \ source \ repos \ Integration Services Project
>   Restore \ Integration Services Project Restore \ Package3.dtsx" due to
>   error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.". This occurs when loading a
>   package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML
>   document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name
>   when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect
>   format. End Error Could not load package "\ areskerjcmdz01 \ c $ \
>   Users \ pamartinez_admin \ source \ repos \ Integration Services
>   Project Restore \ Integration Services Project Restore \
>   Package3.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002. Description: Failed to
>   open package file "\ areskerjcmdz01 \ c $ \ Users \ pamartinez_admin
>   \ source \ repos \ Integration Services Project Restore \ Integration
>   Services Project Restore \ Package3.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005
>   "Access is denied.". This occurs when loading a package and the file
>   cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can
>   be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling
>   LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format. Source:
>   {9A5E45AB-9790-4942-8639-F8C38A51D202} Started: 12:28:26 Finished:
>   12:28:26 Elapsed: 0.078 seconds**

What I need is to be able to run the .bat file from a different computer to the server where the package was created and with a different user than the one that created the package.

Comment: You need some mechanism for pushing the start of the package to the server that is licensed for SQL Server. Some use .NET remoting. Others through SQL agent job.

Comment: Try the following:
- configure an SQL job to run the DTSX package
- configure a stored procedure to run the job
- use the isql command line in a BAT file (executed remotely) to execute the stored procedure in the relevant SQL instance (with SQL credentials and not machine credentials)

When I run the job it throws error. I must correct it but I would like to know if this method is valid.

Comment: isql? What umm version of SQL Server are we working with here?

Comment: As for running it with another user, my prime guess is that it's as the error indicates, file system access is denied.  It looks like you're trying to use a UNC path to navigate to the package. This is using the admin share `C$` so they'll need to be an admin on the box. Then it's trying to navigate to a folder that SQL Server will likely not have access to since it's in your user folder. Also, I don't know if the leading slash is missing from the path but verify it's actually going to `\\areskerjcmdz01` and not `\areskerjcmdz01` as those are quite different resources